# Extra space on top of re-sized PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

It's located in Main VC as a childVC and re-sized. (changed the height and position)

I've tried everything I could find on stack overflow and still no luck.

Nothing has solved my problem.

Methods I've tried :

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

And some others that weren't really gonna help from the beginning just because I'm desperate. Absolutely nothing has worked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out.
Turns out I get this space on top no matter what after adding a TableViewController as childViewController in MainVC.

So you simply change its frame after you add it as childViewController AND adding its view to a content view you've created.(or just self.view)

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

self.homeView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview: self.homeView];
self.homeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];

self.parseTableVC = [[ParseTableVC alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

[self addChildViewController:self.parseTableVC];

self.parseTableVC.view.bounds = self.homeView.bounds;
[self.homeView addSubview:self.parseTableVC.view];
[self.parseTableVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

self.homeView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 80, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 150);

self.parseTableVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.parseTableVC.view.frame.size.width, self.parseTableVC.view.frame.size.height);
```